# Ubuntu 18.04 Fresh Install Apparent Absence of glibc

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, compiling, glibc

I have just installed ubuntu 18.04.

I have run:

```bsh
apt update && apt upgrade
```

I have downloaded llvm from [llvm releases](http://releases.llvm.org/)

When I run:

```
clang file.c -o file
```

Where 'file.c' contains:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc + 1]) { puts("hi"); return 0; }
```

I get an error indicating that: `fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found`

On further investigation, it seems the standard `crt1.o` and friends cannot be found:

```
# Returns nothing
find /usr/lib -name crt1.0
```

In spite of this, running:

```
apt install libc6
```

gives: `libc6 is already the newest version (2.27-3ubuntu1)`

I know that installing `base-devel` would probably solve this problem, however I just want to install `glibc` without other dependencies. Could someone please provide me with some guidance as to how to do this?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I followed Jim's comment, `apt install libc6-dev`. Whilst this solved missing headers and crt.0 variants, I now get the following errors:

```
cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
cannot find -lgcc
cannot find -lgcc_s
```

Do I really have to install gcc despite having clang + glibc?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libc6-dev`.